# Only iron-icon is selectable in paper-item within paper-card

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

[image]

I'm having problems interacting with a selectable list of `paper-item` objects. The `on-tap` (or `on-click`) function is only firing when I click the `iron-icon` within the item, but the rest of the cell is unresponsive. I'm currently displaying the items within a `paper-menu`, but I've tried using `iron-selector` which yields the same behavior.

```
<paper-menu selected="{{selected}}">
    <paper-item on-tap="_onItemTap" role="menuitem">
        <iron-icon icon="cloud-done"></iron-icon>
        <paper-item-body two-line>
            <div>file_1.json</div>
            <div secondary class="second-item-line">Complete</div>
            </paper-item-body>
    </paper-item>
    (... other items)
</paper-menu>
```

The `paper-menu` is nested within a `neon-animated-pages` element and a `paper-card` element. I don't know if that's affecting its behavior at all.

Am I missing anything? Is there a way to make the entire `paper-item` clickable that I just haven't implemented? Or could other elements be interfering?

**Update:**

Upon further digging, I've found that my list of 'paper-item' elements works perfectly if I remove it from the context of the `paper-card` element. The moment I put the list inside a card, it masks the selectable area somehow (but the `iron-icon` is still exposed). Is there any way to expose the entire `paper-item` element to selection in this context? If not, I'll have to redesign my UI to not use `paper-card`.

Comment: I think this may be related to multiple issues open on polymer and its related projects. You can follow this issue to get to other issues on this topic https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/issues/166

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Silly bug, really. Because my list was not inside a `div` with `class="card-content"`, the `paper-item` elements weren't showing on the top layer of the card, becoming unusable. Adding a div with that class around my content solved my issue. Here's how the code turned out:

```
<paper-card>
<div class="card-content">
    <iron-selector selected="{{selected}}">
        <paper-icon-item on-tap="_onItemTap">
            <iron-icon icon="cloud-done" item-icon></iron-icon>
            <paper-item-body two-line>
                <div>file_1.json</div>
                <div secondary>Complete</div>
            </paper-item-body>
        </paper-icon-item>
        <!-- other items -->
    </iron-selector>
</div>
</paper-card>
```